# Logging Device Serial Number Via WMI On ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: vb.net, wmi

We use an ASP.NET web application for our handheld warehouse devices (barcode scanning, etc). We already log every function made on the devices with the user's username, but I've been asked to include in the logs, the device serial number, so that we know who was last to use what.
After a lot of searching, the consensus seems to be that "WMI" is the answer. However all of the examples I found appear to be more geared towards form / console applications rather than web applications. I've been playing around with some code snippets in a test web app but haven't managed to get very far.
Should what I'm trying to accomplish be possible with WMI or am I barking up the wrong tree?
Thanks.

Comment: ASP.NET is a server-side technology - why do you think it can magically get WMI data from remote client devices via their web-browser?

Comment: You don't need to be familiar with WMI to know that HTTP does not allow servers to access the internals of remote computers - otherwise the Internet would be horribly insecure. I wasn't being condescending, I was sincerely asking what your thought-process was.

Comment: I'm a beginner developer and thought that it MAY be possible because I am able to retrieve the computer name and other basic info via a web app. If everyone was an expert, this forum wouldn't be needed.

Comment: How are you able to retrieve the computer name? I'm assuming your application performs a DNS lookup of the request's remote IP address? If so, then that will only work in a LAN environment where all devices _and_ the server share the same DHCP and DNS infrastructure - that won't work on the wider Internet - or on LANs of non-trivial complexity.

Comment: I don't recall how I did it, as it was just test code that has since been removed. It wasn't via WMI though. Getting the computer name was never really a requirement, I was just experimenting with what was and wasn't achievable. And yes, this was LAN only for an intranet application, not the wider internet, as our applications are purely for internal intranet use.